# Generating a list of pairs in R

Tags: r

You must generate a list of pairs of the form:

```
(1,1), (1,2),...,(1,1024), (2,1), (2,2),...,(2,1024),...,(1024,1),   (1024,2),...,(1024,1024). Need a code to R.
```

My decision:

```
paar <- lapply(1:1024, function (x) mapply(c, seq(1,1024), x))
```

Does not exactly.

Comment: Try with `expand.grid(1:1024, 1:1024)` or `CJ(1:1024, 1:1024)` from `data.table`

Comment: Try with two for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(1:1024, 1:1024)
```

Or with `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(1:1024, 1:1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put into data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(1:1024, 1:1024), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Name each column:

```
names(df)=c("x","y")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do for your own proposed solution:

```
lapply(1:n, function (x) mapply(function(x,y) paste0(x,",",y), x, seq(1,n)))
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
expand.grid(1:n,1:n)
```

OR

```
levels(interaction(1:n,1:n))
```

Only the class of the resultant data is different. `list` for your own function, `data.frame` for `expand.grid` solution and `character` for `interaction`.